# Django authentication acting weird. Working "some times", not always

Tags: django, templates, authentication

I'm having some trouble with Django's authentication system. I've managed to set up a login page, logout page and a basic profile page. Now I'm trying to restrict different areas on the site to only authenticated users. It works on some templates, and not on others.

The weirdest, maybe, is that it works/not works in the same template.

This is base.html:

```
<div id="account">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Hello, <a href="{% url accounts-profile %}">{{ user.username }}</a>! | <a href="{% url accounts-logout %}">Log out</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url accounts-login %}">Log in</a>
        or
        <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>


<div id="sidebar">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3 id="plus" style="padding-top: 20px;"><a href="#">Sign up!</a></h3>
        <a href="{% url accounts-login %}">Log in</a>
    {% else %}
        <div style="margin-top: 45px">
            <a href="{% url accounts-profile %}">Profile</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}     
</div>
```

Works in the account-div, but not in the sidebar-div.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could u post your views? are you making sure to `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` request context too?

Comment: It's the base.html-template, so no views specific for it?

Comment: which views are loading templates that extending it?

Comment: all kind of different templates (basically everyone) — this is the sidebar for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3 id="plus" style="padding-top: 20px;"><a href="#">Sign up!</a></h3>
        <a href="{% url accounts-login %}">Log in</a>
 {% else %}
```

why does he have to sign up if he's logged in?
You can try {% if not user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: Fantastic. This has been bugging me all day. Human error. Win!

Comment: I know the feel man, It gets me sometimes at work. Then when I go home and look at the code and i'm like Aha!